# Receiving number of messages from a queue

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am receiving messages from aActive MQ queue.

Is there a way to receive a number of messages in one time? or is that have to be done with a loop?

Further more, if i want to take say 30 messages run a procedure, and only if that procedure works return a  `message.acknowledge();` for all of them.

I mean i dont want to erase those 30 from the queue if the procedure fails.

Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you put those 30 into a message map and send that one message map to the queue? then you can process it at one go rather than waiting for 30 messages to arrive separately and the order you cannot gurantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it in a loop. Usually, it's best to use message-driven beans for consuming messages, but it's not suitable for this case, because they take message by message and you cannot specify the exact number. Thus, use `MessageConsumer` and manual transactions:

```
@Resource
UserTransaction utx;

@Resource(mappedName="jms/yourConnectionFactory");
ConnectionFactory cf;

@Resource(mappedName="jms/yourQueue");
Queue queue;

..    
Connection conn = null;
Session s = null;
MessageConsumer mc = null;
try {
    utx.begin();
    conn = cf.createConnection();
    s = conn.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); //TRANSACTIONAL SESSION!
    mc = s.createConsumer(queue);
    conn.start(); // START CONNECTION'S DELIVERY OF INCOMING MESSAGES
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
          Message msg = mc.receive();
          //BUSINESS LOGIC
    }
    utx.commit();
} catch(Exception ex) {
  ..
} finally { //CLOSE CONNECTION, SESSION AND MESSAGE CONSUMER
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience in ActiveMQ. But I think in case of queue listeners, basic logic should be the same independent to the queue implementation.

For your first question I don't know any way of retrieving multiple messages from a queue. I think best way would be to fetch it one by one inside a loop.

For your second question, message will not be discarded from the queue till the underlying transaction which read the message commits. So you could read whole bunch of messages in a single transaction and roll it back in case of an error. It shouldn't erase any existing messages from the queue.

May I ask why do you need 30 messages to run a procedure. Usually when we use a queue, each message should be able to process independently.

Comment: I want amount of messeages for SQL connection oprimization, i am putting those messeages in DataBase

Comment: Ok. Say 1 of your 30 messages is malformed. So in this case you will not be able to process any of the 30 messages. Since the exception thrown by this message rollbacks the whole transaction for all 30 messages.

Comment: Is the frequency of messages are guranteed in your application? And say 29 messages received in 10 seconds time and it took another 2mins to receive the the 30th message (Ex: keep in mind network delays are unpredictable). First 29 messages will not be processed for 2mins. Won't this affect throughput of your application?